# dtreeviz showing the same feature / split in all nodes of a xgboost decision tree

Tags: google-colaboratory, graphviz, xgboost, decision-tree, dtreeviz

### Problem description

I'm trying to visualize xgboost decision trees using dtreeviz. However, the visualized trees show the same feature name ('ROI: 74; Feature: spkt_welch_density' in my example) and split value (-0.31 in my example) in all nodes, despite showing the correct feature barplot and tree structure. This can be verified by simultaneously visualizing the decision tree using XGBoost's native `plot_tree` function:

[dtreeviz visualization of xgboost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgBtI.png)

[`plot_tree` visualization of xgboost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEOKn.png)

I would like the correct feature name and split value to be shown in all nodes of the dtreeviz tree.

### Data description

X is a 2D numpy array of floats. y is a 1D numpy array of integers. This is a multi-class classification problem and y has 4 classes (0, 1, 2, 3).

### My code

I am using XGBoost with 5-fold cross-validation, so I am going through the 5 sets of train/test indices (`splits`) with a for loop. In each CV round (set of train/test indices), I'm creating an `XGBClassifier` model, optimizing its hyperparameters with RandomizedSearchCV, and fitting it to the train data. I add the dreeviz model created in each cross-validation round to a list so I could visualize them outside the for loop as well. I'm running the code in Google Colab and saving the plots on my Google Drive.

```
random_state = 33

for i, (train_index, test_index) in tqdm(enumerate(splits), total = len(splits)):

    X_train = X[train_index, :]
    X_test = X[test_index, :]
    y_train = y[train_index]
    y_test = y[test_index]

    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state = random_state)
    clf = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions = params, n_iter = 10,
                            scoring = 'balanced_accuracy', n_jobs = -1, cv = 3,
                            verbose = 0, random_state = random_state)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


    viz_model = dtreeviz.model(clf.best_estimator_,
                               tree_index = clf.best_estimator_.best_iteration,
                               X_train = X_train,
                               y_train = y_train,
                               feature_names = feature_names_list, # list of strings
                               target_name = 'Class',
                               class_names = ['AD', 'FTD', 'HC', 'MCI'])
    viz_models.append(viz_model)
    viz_tree = viz_model.view()
    viz_tree.save(f"./fold_{i}_dtreeviz.svg")
    files.download(f"./fold_{i}_dtreeviz.svg")
```

### Possibly helpful clues

1. The feature name that is shown in all nodes is ALWAYS the next to last (idx = -2) name in the `feature_names_list`.
2. In the dtreeviz created during the first cross-validation round (`i = 0` in the code sample), the split values are correct and the feature names are incorrect. In all the following rounds, both the feature names and the split values are incorrect.

### What I've tried so far with no success

1. Updating `graphviz` and `dreeviz` to the latest versions.
2. Creating the xgboost model without cross-validation, RandomizedSearchCV, and outside a for loop.
3. Converting the data to a single pandas dataframe to make my code more similar to [dtreeviz' official xgb example](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/notebooks/dtreeviz_xgboost_visualisations.ipynb).